# Make beamer sidebar transparent (i.e., remove its background)

Tags: beamer, transparency, sidebar

I `\usetheme[width=3cm]{Hannover}` and

```
\setbeamertemplate{background}{}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{}
```

to remove any background, so that the contents of the slides is the only object. I would like to achieve the same effect for the sidebar, but the analogous solution

```
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar}{}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas}{}
```

does not work (I don't see any effect of this). How to remove any background objects from the sidebar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas left}{}` or `\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas right}{}` depending on where your sidebar is located, should work to remove the background color:

> [image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[width=3cm]{Hannover}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas left}{}

\begin{document}
\section{example section}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{an example frame title}
example contents
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked in combination with ``\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{}`` for full transparency. Also worked well with semi-transparent colors provided by setting, for the remaining text items, ``\transparent{0.8}`` from ``\usepackage{transparent}``.